# TikZ edge thickness causing errors in foreach loop

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'm experiencing some weirdness in making a simple TikZ diagram (a comb-shaped graph with variable number of nodes).  The weirdness comes from the style applied to the edge paths.  Here's the (minimal) example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=1.0,%
block/.style = {draw,circle,very thick,minimum size=0.5cm},%
directed/.style ={draw,-triangle 45, shorten >= 0pt, very thick}]

% Parameters
\pgfmathsetmacro{\numXnodes}{int(3)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\strch}{2}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\numXnodes}{
    \path (\strch*\i-\strch, 0) node[block] (x\i) {\i};
    \path (x\i) ++(0,-\strch) node[block] (z\i) {\pgfmathparse{int(\numXnodes+\i)}\pgfmathresult};
    \path (x\i) [directed] -- (z\i);
}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\nnmo}{{int(\numXnodes-1)}}

\foreach \i in {1,...,\nnmo} {
    \pgfmathparse{int(\i+1)}
    \draw (x\i) [draw,-triangle 45,thick] -- (x\pgfmathresult);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above code draws a graph with the right structure/directionality.  However, the edges between "x" nodes are very thin.

The issue is that if I change the style on the line
    `\draw (x\i) [draw,-triangle 45] -- (x\pgfmathresult);`
to `\draw (x\i) [draw,-triangle 45,thick] -- (x\pgfmathresult);` I get an error that says `Package pgf Error: No shape named x0 is known. } (followed by: )`

Any thoughts on why this error would be occurring here and not in the first set of edges drawn with the defined `directed` style (i.e., in the first loop)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

`\pgfmathresult` macro is overwritten at almost every step of code so you need to be quick to use its value. Most probably, `thick` option causes a temporary calculation and removes your result. Instead you can use the `[count=\variable from number]` option.

I would really recommend not using `\i` as the counter since if it doesn't get expanded properly or else, you will have the greek dotless `i` character `iota` in the variable which might go unnoticed until you debug for some time. Moreover, you can also use `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` to get the integer part automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,scale=1.0,%
block/.style = {draw,circle,very thick,minimum size=0.5cm},%
directed/.style ={draw,-triangle 45, shorten >= 0pt, very thick}]

% Parameters
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numXnodes}{3} % \def or \newcommand would also be OK here. 
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\strch}{2}

\foreach \x in {1,...,\numXnodes}{
    \path (\strch*\x-\strch, 0) node[block] (x\x) {\x};
    \path (x\x) ++(0,-\strch) node[block] (z\x) {\pgfmathparse{int(\numXnodes+\x)}\pgfmathresult};
    \path (x\x) [directed] -- (z\x);
}

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\nnmo}{\numXnodes-1}

\foreach \x[count=\xi from 2] in {1,...,\nnmo} {
    \draw (x\x) [draw,-triangle 45,thick] -- (x\xi);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much; your answer was informative on many fronts.  I would like to add that `\pgfmathtruncatemacro`, in addition to being useful, is actually **required** in this example for the `numXnodes` macro, as `\pgfmathsetmacro{int(...)}` will still store a decimal.